# Trim White Spaces to the right of data

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have an Oracle table that contains data on the column `ORG_KEY`. I need to remove the whitespace after the data and retain the same values for all rows. How can I do this like:

```
update migadm.MAINRETAIL_MIG 
   set orgkey = select trim (orgkey) from migadm.MAINRETAIL_MIG
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To strip trailing whitespace you can use the [`rtrim`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rtrim.php) function; for instance:

```
SQL> select rtrim('   hello     ') from dual;

RTRIM('H
--------
   hello
```

I'd imagine your `update` statement would become (notice the extra parenthesis):

```
update migadm.MAINRETAIL_MIG 
   set orgkey = ( select rtrim(orgkey) from migadm.MAINRETAIL_MIG )
```

However, this would update every `orgkey` to be the same so I think you still have a mistake. Maybe you meant something like the following, which will update every `orgkey` to be the right trimmed version of itself?

```
update migadm.MAINRETAIL_MIG 
   set orgkey = rtrim(orgkey)
```

Comment: Tnaks Man Ben that was Nice...I must have Overlooked it.